# DataBaseController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database

So, I develop the app that uses sqlite3 database methods. I have several view controllers so I decided to create a separate class for database methods. I called it DataBaseController.

When I try to load it in my app delegate and view controllers like this:

```
@class DataBaseController;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
DataBaseController *dataBaseController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) DataBaseController *dataBaseController;
@end
```

and then I implement it in FirstViewController.m. But when I try to call in AppDelegate, FirstViewController.m and other controllers the methods I implemented in DataBaseController, for example like:

```
#import "DataBaseController.h"
...
@synthesize dataBaseController;
...
-(void)ViewDidLoad {
[self.dataBaseController openDB];
[self.dataBaseController getRowsFromTable];
[super ViewDidLoad];
}
```

it works only in AppDelegate.

Please, suggest me any ideas on my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to initialize the object.
Your DataBaseController has an function called init right? Thats also a good place to open your database file.

Than do:

```
self.dataBaseController = [[[DataBaseController alloc] init] autoreleas];
NSMutableArray *objs = [self.dataBaseController getRowsFromTable];
```

dont forget to set your object to nill in your dealloc / viewdidunload if you make create a property.

Hope this helps you out.

Rolf

Comment: Yeah, but I added @synthesize dataBaseController in FirstViewController.m Do you think I have to initialize it?

Comment: Its creating getters & setters its not initializing the object for you. Refer: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/